# How to perform Mathematical operations in Mysql through php and Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, web

I am new to Mysql and have faced this problem while learning:- I Created a table named "x"  in **MySql** with 10 columns and wrote a  code in PHP to enter the data into a table from a form in first 8 columns of table and in column 9 I need to a value that will be obtained after the performing mathematical operation on the value in column 2. For instance, I have marks for every student in column 2 of the table and in column 9, I need their percentage (considering total marks are constant). How can I get the percentage in column 9 and update that on every row of column 9? Remember the table is in the database in Mysql.

Comment: You can update your table by following query:
**UPDATE x SET Col9 = CONCAT(round(( Col2/100 * 100 ),2),'%');**
(Assuming total marks = 100)

Comment: Thanks, @DhruvilPatel it worked! and please how can I update that in entire rows of column 9.

Comment: Entire row of column 9 means?

Comment: @DhruvilPatel this shows error `"UPDATE table_name SET column_9 =CONCAT(round((normalised_cost-(Min(normalised_cost)))/(Max(normalised_cost)-Min(normalised_cost))));"`

Answer (score 0):

Before inserting any value into any column, make sure you perform necessary calculation on incoming value.

e.g

```
$column2 = $_POST['column2_field'];

$calculation = $column2 * 50/100 //50 percent
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do your maths in your query. During your select statement you can add a generated column at the end lets say

```
SELECT `column1`, `column2`, `column3`, `column4`, `column5`, `column6`, `column7`, ((`column2` / `column8`) * 100) as `percentage` from TABLE
```

I'm not at a computer but that should be enough to get you the results you need if I understand you correctly.

PHP can also do the job but it is not dynamic as in if the form allows inline editing, the percentage will stay the same.

```
$cal = ($val1 / $val2) * 100;
```

with $val1 and $val2 being generated either from a FORM request or a database row.

Javascript can give you dymanic values if your form works as mentioned.